# call javascript function whenever object is created

Tags: javascript, cordova, iscroll

> How to call any javascript function whenever object is created.

well i am not sure but, is there any way to call javascript function when i create any object.?

```
var myScroll = new iScroll("wrapper");

function objectCreated() {
    alert("yes created")
}
```

here i want to call function **objectCreated** function when i create iScroll object. i know i can call function **objectCreated** from iScroll constructor but i dont want to make change in iscroll.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible for *any* object. That said, you can patch `iScroll` without having to change its source file. Is that acceptable?

Comment: yes, but how can i do that.? i don't have any idea about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't intercept any object creation, but you can patch `iScroll` in this case:

```
// overwrite with a patched function
iScroll = (function(old) {
  return function() {
    // call your interceptor function
    objectCreated();

    // pass everything through to the original iScroll function
    return old.apply(this, arguments);
  };
})(iScroll);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll add a new answer. I patched the iScroll (I'll make a pull request for cubiq later). Demo can be seen here: http://www.hakoniemi.net/labs/iscroll/ and the patched iScroll can be found here: https://github.com/zvona/iscroll/blob/master/src/iscroll.js

In brief the code looks like this:

```
myIScroll = new iScroll("myScroll", {
    "onCreate" : function() { alert('created'); },
    "onDestroy" : function() { alert('destroyed'); }
});
```